# Meteor: Best Method for Passing Mongo Selector from Client to Server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo collection like the following (Foo(X) == keys; Bars == values): EDIT- I come from a relational database background. Obviously my collection doesn't look like the below, but you get the idea...

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  Foo1  |  Foo2  |  Foo3  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| Barbar | Barbar |   Bar  |
|   bar  |  Bar   | BarBar |
|   Bar  | barbar | barBar |
|   ...  |   ...  |   ...  |
```

It's important for me to allow my client to filter the data. Sometimes, all columns will have a filter, other times no columns will have a filter and anywhere in between. Currently, I'm handling the issue as follows:

**Client**

```
Var aFoo1Filter = ["bar"]
Var aFoo2Filter = ["Barbar", "BarBar"]
Var aFoo3Filter = ["barbar", "bar"]
//Where the user can affect the array through some other code
```

**Server**

```
Meteor.publish("foos", function (aFoo1Filter, aFoo2Filter, aFoo3Filter ) {
  return FooCl.find({Foo1: {$in: aFoo1Filter},
                     Foo2: {$in: aFoo2Filter},
                     Foo3: {$in: aFoo3Filter}}, 
                    {limit: 10});
});
```

I'm hoping to simplify this by passing through just one object or one string from the client to the server, but neither attempts have worked. See my attempts, below:

**Attempt #1 - Passing Through a String**

**Client**

```
Var sFilter = "Foo1: {$in: [\"bar\"]},
               Foo2: {$in: [\"Barbar\", \"BarBar\"]},
               Foo3: {$in: [\"barbar\", \"bar\"]}"
```

**Server**

```
Meteor.publish("foos", function (sFilter) {
  return FooCl.find({sFilter}, 
                    {limit: 10});
});
```

//////////////////

**Attempt #2 - Passing Through an Object**

**Client**

```
var oFilter = {
  Foo1: "bar"
}
```

**Server**

```
Meteor.publish("foos", function (oFilter) {
  return FooCl.find({oFilter}, 
                    {limit: 10});
});
```

I don't have my machine with me at the moment, so I can't provide more detail on the type of error thrown. Hopefully will have some more info up tonight. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to subscribe using a selector:

#### Client

```
var selector = {Foo1: {$in: aFoo1Filter}, Foo2: {$in: aFoo2Filter}};
Meteor.subscribe('foos', selector);
```

#### Server

```
Meteor.publish('foos', function (selector) {
  return FooCl.find(selector, {limit: 10});
});
```

However, it's important to recognize that this gives the client the ability to request **any** documents from the `FooCl` collection that she wants. An improved solution is to limit what can be requested by using [match](http://docs.meteor.com/#match) on the selector. For example:

```
Meteor.publish('foos', function(selector) {
  check(selector, {
    Foo1: Match.Optional({$in: [String]}),
    Foo2: Match.Optional({$in: [String]})
  });

  if (!_.isEmpty(selector)) {
    return FooCl.find(selector, {limit: 10});
  }
});
```

This will ensure that `selector` conforms to an acceptable pattern before any documents are sent to the client.

Comment: This did it, thanks!

It looks like my error was in putting curly brackets {} around my sFilter and oFilter.

Also, thanks for the tip regarding the match on the selector!