# Better Pattern for Filtering Collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection named `Games` and I want users to filter through the collection using checkboxes. Every time a checkbox is checked/unchecked, a meteor subscription is called to display the appropriate `Games`

Here's an example of what a subscription might look like (Not proper mongo code):

```
{region: ['east','west','eu'], skill: ['casual','amatuer','pro'], gamemode: ['ctf','dm','etc']}
```

In this particular game you can filter by Region, Skill and Gamemode, with each having multiple combinations.

Edit:

What I need is to create the appropriate selector, depending on which checkboxes are checked.

First, I'm grabbing the checked checkboxes - for each group - and throwing them into an array and then setting that array as a session variable.

```
// Gamemode Group
'click .mode input[type=checkbox]': function(ev, tpl) {
    var mode = tpl.$('.mode input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    });

    var modeArray = $.makeArray(mode);
    Session.set('dotaMode', modeArray);
    returnFilterQuery();
},
```

Then I'm checking each groups array to see if they are populated, and if they are, add them to the final selector (`query`) which I will pass into the subscription. My problem is I have to check for each possible scenario and its nothing but `if` statements, and once I start adding more groups (gamemode, region, skill, etc.) to search by, there will be so many more combinations.

```
function returnFilterQuery(){
    //check all fields and create a query object
    var query = { game: 'dota' };
    var gamemode = Session.get('dotaMode');
    var region = Session.get('dotaRegion');
    var skill = Session.get('dotaSkill');

    // if no region or skill is selected, show user all
    if (region.length && skill.length && gamemode.length) {
        query.region = { $in: region };
        query.skill = { $in: skill };
        query.gamemode = { $in: gamemode };
    } else if (region.length && !skill.length && gamemode.length) {
        query.region = { $in: region };
        query.gamemode = { $in: gamemode };
    } else if (!region.length && skill.length && gamemode.length) {
        query.skill = { $in: skill };
        query.gamemode = { $in: gamemode };
    } else if (!region.length && !skill.length && gamemode.length) {
        query.gamemode = { $in: gamemode };
    } else if (region.length && skill.length && !gamemode.length) {
        query.region = { $in: region };
        query.skill = { $in: skill };
    } else if (region.length && !skill.length && !gamemode.length) {
        query.region = { $in: region };
    } else if (!region.length && skill.length && !gamemode.length) {
        query.skill = { $in: skill };
    }

    return Session.set('dotaFilter', query);
};
```

Hopefully this all makes sense. I'm sure there has to be a better way, I'm just not able to think of something right now. Thanks.

Comment: This feels pretty similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937772/meteor-best-method-for-passing-mongo-selector-from-client-to-server). My answer there was to pass a selector to the publish function - that may be appropriate here as well.

Comment: @DavidWeldon my problem isn't necessarily pub/sub, but more about producing the correct selector, depending on which checkboxes are checked. I'm going to edit my original post to explain in more detail what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm feeling particularly inspired to answer this because of the DotA reference. :)

So if I understand the problem correctly, you should not need to check every combination, but rather repeatedly add keys to the `query` object based on the contents of three session variables. I think the following is logically equivalent to your `returnFilterQuery` function above.

```js
var returnFilterQuery = function() {
  var query = {game: 'dota'};

  var modifyQueryIfArray = function(key, sessionKey) {
    var value = Session.get(sessionKey);
    if (!_.isEmpty(value))
      query[key] = {$in: value};
  };

  modifyQueryIfArray('gamemode', 'dotaMode');
  modifyQueryIfArray('region', 'dotaRegion');
  modifyQueryIfArray('skill', 'dotaSkill');

  return Session.set('dotaFilter', query);
};
```

Note that `isEmpty` may be a safer check than `length` in case the session variable isn't an array.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great and is so much easier to add additional games and filtering options!