# Construct a selector with if statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session, meteor

I create a MongoDB selector from some session variables. If the session value is null, the selector should not include the condition.

I have a selector

```
return Session.get('title') ? { title: Session.get('title') } : {};
```

which works as it should; however, I want to filter on more session values.

If I add another one, I get

```
var title = Session.get('title');
var age = Session.get('age');

if (title && age) {
  return {
    title: title,
    age: age
  };
} else if (title) {
  return {
    title: title
  };
} else if (age) {
  return {
    age: age
  }
} else {
  return {}
}
```

and it will only get more complicated when I add another session value.

How can I obtain the same result in a smarter way?

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: Yes my code works, but isn't it an unrealistic approach if I have 10+ session variables to construct my selector from? I don't see it as a simple opnionated improvement

Comment: Well, the more variables you will have the more horrible it will look. There is indeed a lot of room for improvement, _too much room_. It's impossible to give a definitive answer because there is a lot of ways to achieve this, and the "best" ways depend on code styles and personal preferences.

Comment: @Jamgreen This is pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375477/better-pattern-for-filtering-collections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an array to hold all of your possible values, then you just add to this array when a new value is added.

```
var sessionVars = ['title', 'age'];
var result = {};
sessionVars.forEach(function(varName) {
  var value = Session.get(varName);
  if (value) {
    result[varName] = value;
  }
});
return result;
```